# How to compare text files character by character using Linux

Tags: linux

I am pretty new to Linux, and I would like to know how can I compare two text files in Linux in order to determine the first character of difference between them. Any help will be appreciate it

Comment: [man cmp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp)

Comment: [man diff](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff)

Comment: Thanks Frederic, I did not know about cmp command. diff is not an option because I am looking for a character by character comparison. A simple cmp file file1 shows me the information that I need